# 3.5" HDD spinning up via usb adapter but not via sata

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, sata

I have a 14TB WD Elements external HDD. It's about 1 year old. Then I opened the case to use it as an internal HDD.

If I use the USB adapter from the case everything works fine (The adapter is a small circuit board).

But when I use a SATA and a common HDD power cable the drive doesn't even start spinning up and not getting detected by the BIOS.

**And** I have multiple drives of this exact model bought at the same order and every drive else works fine via USB and via SATA.

So it sounds to me there must be an issue with the drive itself, but I also read about formatting and partition errors.

**Does anybody know what to do here? Thank you :)**

PS: The data is not important. I can format it without any problems if necessary.

Comment: If you can replace the HDD with one of the others **in the same place** then the drive is somehow damaged; STRANGE.  If you're using a separate cable to use this disk; replace the cable.

Comment: @Hannu Thanks for your comment. Yes it's weird. I use the exact same cables etc. I only change the drive. So I probably need to use it as USB in future.

Comment: Are you sure the internal drive is actually SATA?  It's entirely possible it's actually SAS.  SAS and SATA to the untrained eye look alike.  HDD Manufactures are known to put any old model of HDD in their external HDD enclosures.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, 100% sure. Also because I think I wouldn't be able to connect my sata and power cable to a sas drive.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is called shucking a hard drive. What you have, most probably, is called the **3.3V Pin Issue**. There are many ways [online](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Fix-the-33V-Pin-Issue-in-White-Label-Disks-/) dealing with it.